# Can Ubuntu One bookmarks sync work in Firefox 5?

Tags: ubuntu-one, bookmarks

In Firefox 5.0 on Ubuntu 11.04, Bindwood is disabled as "incompatible with FF 5.0". The xpi on Launchpad can't be installed for the same reason.

I'm aware of various bug reports concerning bookmark sync, and indeed I never actually got it working in earlier versions of Ubuntu and Firefox, but this Bindwood incompatibility seems to close off any prospect of getting it working.

I know about Firefox's own sync, too, but I'd rather get Ubuntu One's working, partly so as not to have to set up yet another account.

Is a fix being worked on, or am I missing something? I had thought the latest Ubuntu would offer the best chance of working bookmarks sync.

Looks as though Firefox's built-in sync may be the answer, after all. Expecially as, following another routine upgrade, I'm now using Firefox 6. That's too bad - but I guess Ubuntu could argue it's not worth their while to duplicate something that now works in Firefox.

Comment: Have you looked at Firefox's own Sync?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu One does not support Bookmark-Sync any more: [Putting bookmark sync to bed](http://voices.canonical.com/ubuntuone/?p=1282)

Answer (score 0):

Install the [Addon Compatibility Reporter](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/add-on-compatibility-reporter/) extension -- with that, you can force Firefox to treat this extension (or any extension) as compatible.  In (common) cases where an extension just needs a compatible-version-bump, this is the perfect workaround.

It's of course possible that the extension is legitimately incompatible due to Firefox code changes, in which case this might cause problems.  It's probably worth backing up your `~/.mozilla` directory before doing this, just in case.

Having said that, I've personally never hit any issues from using the Addon Compatibility Reporter.

Comment: I've given the Compatibility Reporter a go but, afer appearing to allow it, it turned off Bindwood without being asked. Seems it really doesn't work in Firefox > 4, after all. Thank you for mentioning the Compatibility Reporter, though; I hadn't heard of it, and it does look useful.

Comment: I don't know what Bindwood is or why ACR turned it off, but ACR definitely works in Firefox > 4  (I'm using it on nightly builds of Firefox development trunk currently).  It's actively maintained and should do the right thing -- might be worth poking around a bit more, if it wasn't working yet.  If it mistakenly disabled an extension, it should still give you the option to re-enable it in under "Tools | Addons", in the "Extensions" side-tab.

Comment: Sorry, I meant Bindwood didn't work in FF<4, not that ACR didn't. ACR seems to be working just fine, but, in the case of Bindwood only, the "Preferences", "[Dis|en]able" and "Remove" buttons in Tools|Addons are now missing altogether. I take this to mean that Bindwood really doesn't work in Firefox 6. And I have to admit I've now taken the advice I got earlier, and gone for Firefox's own sync functionality (with works nicely, despite what I'd heard earlier).

Comment: s/with/which/ - sorry.